# taking regions identifier from another method?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, notifications

I m trying to do location based project. When I get the notification i will press yes button and go to place's page in the application. To do this process I should take notifications title but i'm creating the notification in the Core Location's didenterregion method. For notification action I should use didreceiveresponse method. How can i take the title of the notification from didenterregion for didreceiveresponse method?

here is my code

```
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: [.alert,.sound,.badge],
            completionHandler: { (didAllow,error) in


        }
        )

        let answerYes = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "answerYes", title: "Evet", options: UNNotificationActionOptions.foreground)
        let answerCancel = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "answerCancel", title: "İptal", options: UNNotificationActionOptions.foreground)

        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "myCategory", actions: [answerYes,answerCancel], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
     let topkapiLatitude: CLLocationDegrees = 41.013
        let topkapiLongitude: CLLocationDegrees = 28.984
        let topkapiCenter: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(topkapiLatitude, topkapiLongitude)
        let topkapiRadius: CLLocationDistance = CLLocationDistance(100.0)
        let topkapiIdentifier: String = "Topkapı Sarayı"

        let topkapiRegion  = CLCircularRegion(center: topkapiCenter, radius: topkapiRadius, identifier: topkapiIdentifier)

        let yrbtnLatitude: CLLocationDegrees = 41.0081
        let yrbtnLongitude: CLLocationDegrees = 28.9778
        let yrbtnCenter: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(yrbtnLatitude, yrbtnLongitude)
        let yrbtnRadius: CLLocationDistance = CLLocationDistance(100.0)
        let yrbtnIdentifier: String = "Yerebatan Sarnıcı"

        let yrbtnRegion  = CLCircularRegion(center: yrbtnCenter, radius: yrbtnRadius, identifier: yrbtnIdentifier)

        locationManager.distanceFilter = 10
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        topkapiRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
        yrbtnRegion.notifyOnEntry = true

        locationManager.delegate=self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: topkapiRegion)
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: yrbtnRegion)
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        return true
    }


    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if response.actionIdentifier == "answerYes" {

    }
        else {

        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = region.identifier
        content.subtitle = "You are at \(region.identifier) now"
        content.body = "Do you want to learn history of this place?"
        content.badge = 1
        content.categoryIdentifier = "myCategory"


        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 2, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerDone", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)








    }
```

Comment: 1. AFAIK The `response` has a [`notification`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationresponse) *property* so you can use that to extract `title` 2. I'm not sure but I think you're making it hard for yourself...you can create a locationBased Notification using `UNLocationNotificationTrigger` for a good simple example see [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-usernotifications-framework--cms-27250)

Comment: I have tried before do this but i cannot take the notification. But with this example i will try one more time thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can your custom object through **UNMutableNotificationContent's** userInfo property.

```
content.userInfo = ["yourkey": "Your object"] as [String : Any] // set in region method
```

And get in ** didReceive**

```
print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo) // this is your data
```

Comment: yes i can print by region  name. But print is a little bit different. Example [AnyHashable("region"): Dolmabahçe Sarayı] . But i want to make if loop and if i say (if response.notification.request.content.userInfo == "Dolmabahçe Sarayı" ) will it work?

Comment: No it will not work because userinfo is NSDictionary class object.

Comment: let topkapiIdentifier: String = "Topkapı Sarayı"